# Flex responsive max-width with space-between

Tags: css, flexbox

I am adding 3 columns that are 400px wide max and adding space between them using `space-between`.

```
.wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: stretch;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.item {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 400px;
}
```

When I make the screen size smaller, the items are not responsive. They just collapse below each other. If I remove `flex-wrap` I start getting more than 3 columns per row and they are below 400px.

How can I get 3 responsive columns with space between in flex?

Percent for the width can't be used because the space between items has to look the same at any screen size.

Comment: `They just collapse below each other.` --> you expect what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should drop `width: 100%` if you do not want them to occupy the whole width of the parent. And since you are using flex on the parent, you might as well use flex properties on the children and have these:

```
.item {
  flex-basis: 33%;   /* <-- Added in lieu of the width */
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 0px 5px;   /* <-- Added to give left/right margins */
}
```

If you only have those 3 children in the parent, then you could also do this:

```
.item {
  flex-grow: 1;      /* <-- Lets them grow equally */
  flex-shrink: 1;    /* <-- Lets them shrink equally. OPTIONAL as 1 is the default */
  max-width: 400px;  
  margin: 0px 5px;   /* <-- Added to give left/right margins */
}
```

The shorthand for the last one is this:

```
.item {
  flex: 1;           /* <-- Lets them grow/shrink equally */
  max-width: 400px;  
  margin: 0px 5px;   /* <-- Added to give left/right margins */
}
```

Also, if you only have those 3 children in the parent, you may want to remove `flex-wrap: wrap;` from `.wrapper` if you do not want the children elements to wrap. It will not happen in this case, since the children have percentage widths which add up to 100%. But it could be confusing and it contradicts with your intent.

Answer (score 0):

If you want three columns, change the width property to `33%` in your `.item` declaration instead of `100%`.

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/odbnpswa/)

Currently, all your "columns" are fighting to be 100% of the parent node. Here's a great [explanation of using css flex](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) from css-tricks.com.